# QGIS and CRS _ 2 different CRS for one project

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a project which is based on the CRS "EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe"
I would like to have a background with the European continent; I thought about adding the "OSM Standard" layer. This is in CRS "EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator".
When I try to export and save the OSM layer as an ESRI .hdr Labelled with the CRS of my project, I have an error; for details see below:

> An alternative, ballpark-only transform was used when transforming
> coordinates between EPSG:3035 - ETRS89-extended / LAEA Europe and
> EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator. The results may not match those
> obtained by using the preferred operation:
> +proj=pipeline +step +inv +proj=webmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +step +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80
>
> Possibly an incorrect choice of operation was made for transformations
> between these reference systems. Check the Project Properties and
> ensure that the selected transform operations are applicable over the
> whole extent of the current project.

Do you know what can be done?

Comment: Why do you feel the need to save a WMS as `.hdr`?

Comment: Hi Erik, just because it's my only option... I don't the option to choose ESRI alone

Comment: But it's a WMS. It is there, when you need it and have an internet connection.

Comment: Is that actually an error, or just a warning? Furthermore, if you really need to export the WMS, you can export it in its native CRS and QGIS will most likely reproject it on the fly when you add it to your project with a different CRS anyway.

Comment: We're not quite sure what you attempt to achieve in the end. If you could provide more information about your workflow and what the end result should be, it would be easier to tell you which options you have.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works